# Using a third table in simple left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an simple sql that is fine but I need data from another table and getting error below: the trick is that each people_id might have more than one program_name (we are an agency with many programs) I want to show Full Name, the alt_id info and programs they are in. I want to show programs even if they do not have an alt_id.

```
select b.*, c.program_name, a.full_name 
from all_clients_view a 
left outer join alt_id_view b
on a.people_id = b.people_id
```

*** till here it is fine.
This part is giving error:

```
Where a.people_id IN (select program_name
                      from program_enrollment_view c
                      where a.people_id = c.people_id)
```

Error:

> The multi-part identifier "c.program_name" could not be bound.

Comment: Why are you comparing a `people_id` to a `program_name`.  Something looks wrong.

Comment: a.people_id should be = to the people_id in the third table then we want the program_name.

Comment: You can't select `c.program_name`, since `c` is not in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Why don't you simply inner join c on a?

Comment: We have data from b as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you simply want `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from program_enrollment_view pev
              where a.people_id = pev.people_id
             )
```

Comparing a "people_id" to a "program_name" doesn't make sense to me.

If you want to return the program name, you want an additional `join`:

```
select ac.full_name, ai.*, pev.program_name, 
from all_clients_view ac left join
     alt_id_view ai
     on ac.people_id = ai.people_id left join
     program_enrollment_view pev
     on ac.people_id = pev.people_id;
```

Notes:

- This uses table aliases that make sense, rather than `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Highly recommended!
- You want to `left join` the view `program_enrollment_view`, if you want rows with no matches.
- Because you are selecting `*` from the second table, I am guessing that an `inner join` is more appropriate.

Comment: Currently it makes a new row for each alt_id and each program. So if someone has 2 alt if and 2 programs it makes 4 rows. Is there a way to get everything on one row, the name, all id's, all programs?

Comment: @Pinkab . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.  This question appears to have been answered.